# static IP handling

Tags: linux-networking, ip-routing

I have two IPs on one interface, when the packets are sent out it is always picking first IP but I want the packets to be sent out on second IP

I have two servers in HA (Active-standby) configurtion.

server 1 is assigned with in eth0 10.1.1.1 adn server 2 is with eth0 10.1.1.2.
and the floating IP 10.1.1.3 will be assigned to active machine. whichever is active, that machine will take 10.1.1.3 IP on eth0.

now the problem is, when packets are sent out, it always pick the 10.1.1.1 or 10.1.1.2 instead of 10.1.1.3. How can i make the server to sent out the packets on 10.1.1.3 in this case.

Comment: What are you using to manage the HA configuration?